# Automatic table width

Tags: width

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{table}
    \label{table:table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \textbf{1}     & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}    \\ \hline \hline
    A     &   blahblahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah   &   blahblahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblah      \\ \hline
    B            &   b   &   b     \\ \hline
    C      &     c     &    c   
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table is not contained between the page margins. I want it to automatically adapt to the width of the page, or, alternativelly, I want to be able to fix the width of each column manually, in such a way that the text in each cell fill several cell lines if necessary.

I already checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246391/automatic-table-widths) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350156/tabu-automatic-manual-table-width) but I think no one gives an explanation for what I am looking for.

Comment: You write that your objective is "I want [the table] to automatically adapt to the width of the page". In table design, there are lots of parameters that can be tweaked. In consequence, there are potentially lots of degrees of freedom. However, there are always lots of constraints that must be met as well. Two such constraints might be "all columns must be equally wide" and  "automatic text wrapping not allowed in some columns". Your stated objective doesn't list *any* constraints other than that the overall width of the table must not exceed `\textwidth`. Please state a few more.

Comment: Take a look at the tabularx package

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

What you are trying to do is often achieved with the `tabularx` package. It provides an `X` column that takes an automatically calculated width. The width of each of the `X` columns is calculated from the argument to the `tabularx` environment, minus the space reservations for other, non-`X` columns, and divided equally between the `X` columns. You can further modify the `X` columns with the `>` syntax before the column specifier, e.g. by centring the column: `>{\centering}X`. Note that if the last column is also modified in that way, it needs to include `\arraybackslash` for reasons explained, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387737/what-is-arraybackslash-doing-on-my-table-column), or in the `tabularx` manual.

I took the liberty to load the `booktabs` package as well and inserted its nice `\midrule` to replace the vertical bars from your original table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{table}
    \label{table:table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \textbf{1}     & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}    \\ \midrule
    A     &   A very long line that automatically breaks  &   Somtimes it can be a good idea to consider having less characters in a table cell if at all possible\\ 
    B            &   b   &   b     \\ 
    C      &     c     &    c   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As a further modification, your column specification could also look like:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l >{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

as the first column does not include any multi-line text. In this case, the width for the two `X` columns will be

```
(\textwidth minus 6\tabcolsep minus (width of first l column)) divided by 2
```

If you wanted to have a fixed width for one of the columns, you could use the usual `p{width}`, e.g.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1cm} >{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and the width for the remaining `X` columns would update according to the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Consider p{0.4\textwidth} option instead of plain |c|. You might also find [booktab package](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) helpful. Your table will look nicer.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{table}
    \label{table:table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}}
    \textbf{1}     & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}    \\ \hline \hline
    A     &   blahblahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah   &   blahblahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblah      \\ \hline
    B            &   b   &   b     \\ \hline
    C      &     c     &    c   
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously you can change 0.4\textlength with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`tabulary` is similar to `tabularx` but tries to balance the cells vertically, that is, cells with more text will be automatically wider. You may also consider using `booktabs` for a nicer look.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{caption,tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{table}
\label{table:table}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{c|C|C}
\textbf{1} & \textbf{2}                                                                & \textbf{3}    \\ \hline \hline
A          & blahbla hbl ahbl ahbl ahb lahblah bla hblahb lahb la hblah blahb lahb lah & blah bla hblah blah bla hbla h blah blahbl ahblah      \\ \hline
B          & b                                                                         & b     \\ \hline
C          & c                                                                         & c
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]